# Creating animation with drag and drop

Tags: android, android-animation

I saw this animation in an app.

[image]

As we can see in image we drag icon then drop on another icon, I was able to find a way to do drag and drop but not able to find a way to get the effect as shown in the above image.

Can someone please help me how to do this.